# Speeding up sql query to get monthly data

Tags: mysql

I am getting analytics for monthly stats and my query seems to be very slow I am not great with mysql and I am not sure what is the best way maybe this is correct. After searching on StackOverflow I found what I think is this best way to get the data.

I need to get a tally/count of stats per day over a month I have one table for the days of the month like this.

[image]

And I am running the query against my stats table like this.

```
SELECT day, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM stats WHERE DAYOFMONTH( stats.timestamp ) = DW.day_id AND MONTH( stats.timestamp ) = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND YEAR( stats.timestamp ) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND stats.user_id = 1) AS taly FROM daysoffthemonth DW
```

This is my output from that query.

[image]

This works but like stated above its starting to get very slow especially now my stats table is starting to populate with lots of data.

Would appreciate any advice on best practice?

Thanks

The result from query suggested in comments.

[image]

Comment: What is a day id? You appear to have 3 times as many columns here as you actually need

Comment: day_id is taken from the daysoffthemonth table I have set up in the first image.

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid subquery ins column result  ..
Instead of a subquery try using a join

```
 SELECT DW.day, ifnull(COUNT(*),0) taly
 FROM daysoffthemonth DW 
 LEFT  JOIN stats ON DAYOFMONTH( stats.timestamp ) = DW.day_id 
    AND  AND MONTH( stats.timestamp ) = MONTH(CURDATE()) 
      AND AND YEAR( stats.timestamp ) = YEAR(CURDATE()) 
        AND stats.user_id = 1
 GROUP BY DW.day
```

or for avoid 1

```
select DW.day, ifnull(t.my_count,0) taly
from daysoffthemonth DW 
left join (
  select DAYOFMONTH( stats.timestamp ) day ,  COUNT(*) my_count
  from stats
  where  MONTH( stats.timestamp ) = MONTH(CURDATE()) 
    AND YEAR( stats.timestamp )= YEAR(CURDATE())
  group by  DAYOFMONTH( stats.timestamp ) ) t  on DW.day = t.day
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work unfortunately I only get one result not a result for each day?

Comment: I updated the question to show what I currently get which I am trying to mimic but fastest thanks

Comment: I have update the answer for result also when not matching  ..use left join instead of inner join

Comment: I have update the question to show the result i get from your query thanks

Comment: This works great and cuts my query time in half ;) but not quite there yet my taly always returns 1 instead of 0 looking into this the ifnull function doesn't seem to have any effect

Comment: answer updated  .with another query  .. hope this don't return 1 but 0

Comment: You, sir, are a legend I would happily buy you a beer if you have anything setup ;)

Comment: @user1503606  thank you very much .. for beer it is as if you had done it ... I drink it for your health